# How to table name for a view in Big Query

Tags: google-bigquery

I tried in google search but unable to how to find table name for a view in Big Query and also I would like to know how to delete view in Big Query.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for your created views, these are within the [BigQuery UI](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/bigquery-web-ui#bq_ui_overview).

To delete a view, you could follow [these instructions](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/managing-views#deleting_a_view).